# How to specify Phi Beta Kappa membership?

Tags: united-states, honor-societies

I am writing a letter of recommendation for a student whose record includes membership in the Phi Beta Kappa honor society.  How do I express this?

- Jane was named to Phi Beta Kappa.
- Jane was awarded Phi Beta Kappa.
- Jane earned Phi Beta Kappa.
- Jane was inducted into Phi Beta Kappa.

Or something else?

Comment: Moderators: Feel free to migrate to English Language Usage if that is more appropriate.  I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Inducted" is the term normally associated with the process of joining an honor society, whether it is a group such as Phi Beta Kappa or Tau Beta Pi, or a professional society such as the National Academy of Science, or even something cultural, like a sports hall of fame.

As a usage note, though, the term "inducted" is normally accompanied by a temporal reference.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply: Jane was a member of the Phi Beta Kappa honor society. Feel free to add relevant information, e.g. how long was she member, any outstanding exploits, perhaps even a statement how "elite" that particular society is, i.e. how hard it is to get in and her related accomplishments.

Comment: I think I'd like to stress that membership is not simply purchased but is an honor, without going into the details.  Since the letter is for a U.S. scholarship, I can assume the reader will be familiar with it.  (I realize my second sentence somewhat contradicts the first one.)

Comment: I'm aware that it is an honor, I'm sorry, but I don't see where I suggested it can be purchased. Can you be more specific what lacks clarity? I'll be happy to edit my answer. However, I still feel that the most efficient approach is the simple one. Even more so, if, as you say it, the reader is familiar with the society.

Comment: You didn't, but to me the term member has been tainted by the triviality of becoming a member of most organizations.  I meant no offense.